# Replicating HdrHistogram's HistogramPlotter Output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to recreate the [HistogramPlotter](https://hdrhistogram.github.io/HdrHistogram/plotFiles.html) output utilizing pandas and matplotlib.

The output from the provided link looks something like:
[image: Output from HistogramPlotter]

The output from my current script is considerably more "squished" at the tail:
[image: Output from Python Script]

I'm wondering how I could make this with similar dimensions?

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('consumer.hgrm', skiprows=4, skipfooter=3, engine='python', delim_whitespace=True)
df.columns = ['Value', 'Percentile', 'TotalCount', 'LastColumn']

# Transform Percentile to accommodate the percentage scale
df['Percentile'] = 100 - (100 - df['Percentile']*100)

plt.figure(figsize=[10,8])

# Create an evenly-spaced scale (0-100) for plotting
df['Plot_X'] = np.linspace(0, 100, len(df))

plt.plot(df['Plot_X'], df['Value'])

# Custom x-ticks
ticks_labels = [0, 90, 99, 99.9, 99.99, 99.999, 99.9999, 100]
ticks_positions = np.interp(ticks_labels, df['Percentile'], df['Plot_X'])

plt.xticks(ticks_positions, labels=[str(tick) for tick in ticks_labels])

plt.xlabel('Percentile')
plt.ylabel('Latency')
plt.title('Latency by Percentile')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

This is the `consumer.hgrm` In case anyone wants to try it for themselves:

```
#[Overall percentile distribution between 0.000 and <Infinite> seconds (relative to StartTime)]
#[StartTime: 1686845426.968 (seconds since epoch), Thu Jun 15 09:10:26 PDT 2023]
       Value     Percentile TotalCount 1/(1-Percentile)

     0.00000 0.000000000000        709           1.00
     0.00001 0.100000000000    2476441           1.11
     0.00001 0.200000000000    4356006           1.25
     0.00001 0.300000000000    8567334           1.43
     0.00001 0.400000000000   10722387           1.67
     0.00001 0.500000000000   12908630           2.00
     0.00001 0.550000000000   12908630           2.22
     0.00002 0.600000000000   15124819           2.50
     0.00002 0.650000000000   15124819           2.86
     0.00002 0.700000000000   17277174           3.33
     0.00002 0.750000000000   17277174           4.00
     0.00002 0.775000000000   17277174           4.44
     0.00002 0.800000000000   19201856           5.00
     0.00002 0.825000000000   19201856           5.71
     0.00002 0.850000000000   19201856           6.67
     0.00002 0.875000000000   19201856           8.00
     0.00002 0.887500000000   20598743           8.89
     0.00002 0.900000000000   20598743          10.00
     0.00002 0.912500000000   20598743          11.43
     0.00002 0.925000000000   20598743          13.33
     0.00002 0.937500000000   20598743          16.00
     0.00002 0.943750000000   20598743          17.78
     0.00002 0.950000000000   21368551          20.00
     0.00002 0.956250000000   21368551          22.86
     0.00002 0.962500000000   21368551          26.67
     0.00002 0.968750000000   21368551          32.00
     0.00002 0.971875000000   21368551          35.56
     0.00002 0.975000000000   21368551          40.00
     0.00002 0.978125000000   21368551          45.71
     0.00002 0.981250000000   21368551          53.33
     0.00002 0.984375000000   21659778          64.00
     0.00002 0.985937500000   21659778          71.11
     0.00002 0.987500000000   21659778          80.00
     0.00002 0.989062500000   21659778          91.43
     0.00002 0.990625000000   21659778         106.67
     0.00002 0.992187500000   21659778         128.00
     0.00002 0.992968750000   21659778         142.22
     0.00002 0.993750000000   21659778         160.00
     0.00002 0.994531250000   21659778         182.86
     0.00002 0.995312500000   21728114         213.33
     0.00002 0.996093750000   21728114         256.00
     0.00002 0.996484375000   21728114         284.44
     0.00002 0.996875000000   21728114         320.00
     0.00002 0.997265625000   21728114         365.71
     0.00002 0.997656250000   21728114         426.67
     0.00002 0.998046875000   21728114         512.00
     0.00002 0.998242187500   21740997         568.89
     0.00002 0.998437500000   21740997         640.00
     0.00002 0.998632812500   21740997         731.43
     0.00002 0.998828125000   21744511         853.33
     0.00003 0.999023437500   21748087        1024.00
     0.00004 0.999121093750   21750177        1137.78
     2.30725 0.999218750000   21753164        1280.00
     2.30726 0.999316406250   21757285        1462.86
     2.30726 0.999414062500   21757285        1706.67
     2.30818 0.999511718750   21764315        2048.00
     2.30818 0.999560546875   21764315        2275.56
     2.30818 0.999609375000   21764315        2560.00
     2.30818 0.999658203125   21764315        2925.71
     2.30818 0.999707031250   21764315        3413.33
     2.30818 0.999755859375   21764315        4096.00
     2.30819 0.999780273438   21768288        4551.11
     2.30819 0.999804687500   21768288        5120.00
     2.30819 0.999829101563   21768288        5851.43
     2.30819 0.999853515625   21768288        6826.67
     2.30819 0.999877929688   21768288        8192.00
     2.30819 0.999890136719   21768288        9102.22
     2.30819 0.999902343750   21768288       10240.00
     2.30819 0.999914550781   21768288       11702.86
     2.30819 0.999926757813   21768288       13653.33
     2.30819 0.999938964844   21768288       16384.00
     2.30819 0.999945068359   21768288       18204.44
     2.30819 0.999951171875   21768288       20480.00
     2.30901 0.999957275391   21768699       23405.71
     2.30901 0.999963378906   21768699       27306.67
     2.30901 0.999969482422   21768699       32768.00
     2.30901 0.999972534180   21768699       36408.89
     2.30902 0.999975585938   21768857       40960.00
     2.30902 0.999978637695   21768857       46811.43
     2.30904 0.999981689453   21769288       54613.33
     2.30904 1.000000000000   21769288
#[Mean    =      0.00183, StdDeviation   =      0.06471]
#[Max     =      2.30904, Total count    =     21769288]
#[Buckets =           13, SubBuckets     =       262144]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the [Source code](https://github.com/BrunoBonacci/hdr-plot/blob/0c5b506b39e13a6087feda987c01ede053e2ca3e/hdr_plot/hdr_plot.py#L134) of `plot_percentiles`, you need to set the x-axis to `logit`.

Here are some changes based on your code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

df = pd.read_csv('consumer.hgrm', skiprows=4, skipfooter=3, engine='python', delim_whitespace=True)
df.columns = ['Value', 'Percentile', 'TotalCount', 'LastColumn']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10,8])
plt.plot(df['Percentile'], df['Value'])
# Custom x-ticks
ticks_labels = [0.2, 0.9, 0.99, 0.999, 0.9999, 0.99999, 0.999999, 0.9999999]
ticks_labels_str = ["20%", "90%", "99%", "99.9%", "99.99%","99.999%", "99.9999%", "99.99999%"]                       
ax.set_xscale('logit')
plt.xticks(ticks_labels)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(ticks_labels_str))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
plt.xlabel('Percentile')
plt.ylabel('Latency')
plt.title('Latency by Percentile')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The result :
[image]